# Is it possible to get the payload data of a JavaScript socket io and print it using Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-channels

I have this JavaScript project that uses socket io and console the data.

```
const   = generateMockData(deviceId);
        console.log(payload)
        io.of("/").emit("data", JSON.stringify(payload));
```

And this is the generated mock data

```
function generateMockData(deviceId) {
  const contaminants = [
    {
      id: 9,
      ave: chance.floating({ min: 5, max: 5.5, fixed: 7 }),
      ave_reduction: chance.floating({ min: 0, max: 1, fixed: 1 }),
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      ave: chance.floating({ min: 5, max: 5.5, fixed: 7 }),

      ave_reduction: chance.floating({ min: 0, max: 1, fixed: 1 }),
    },
    {
      id: 14,
      ave: chance.floating({ min: 5, max: 5.5, fixed: 7 }),
      ave_reduction: chance.floating({ min: 0, max: 1, fixed: 1 }),
    },
    {
      id: 15,
      ave: chance.floating({ min: 5, max: 5.5, fixed: 7 }),
      ave_reduction: chance.floating({ min: 0, max: 1, fixed: 1 }),
    },
  ];
```

socket io listening to this port

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

in my console it looks like this

```
 contaminants: [
    { id: 9, ave: 5.4897571, ave_reduction: 0.5 },
    { id: 10, ave: 5.4942647, ave_reduction: 0.7 },
    { id: 14, ave: 5.316183, ave_reduction: 0.5 },
    { id: 15, ave: 5.0806739, ave_reduction: 0.9 }
  ],
```

is it possible to pass this payload data (console data) to Django? I tried using httpresponse in Django but it's not getting the data I want. The javascript and the django are in different projects.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse  
response = HttpResponse("http://localhost:3000/")
        print(response)
```

print response

```
<HttpResponse status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

my urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index)
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'base.html', context={'text': "data"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    //POST payload to django
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://your-django-page/app-name");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
    xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify({ "port": port }));
});
```

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        port = request.POST.get("port")
        return render(request, 'base.html', context={"text": "data", "port":port})
    return render(request, 'base.html', context={"text": "data", "port":port})
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name="index")
]
```

## To avoid cross origin error:

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...    
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    ...
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Comment: Error: Cross origin null forbidden

Comment: You need to install `django-cors-headers`. I updated the answer.

Comment: I followed your answer, and the error is gone. Now, how can I print the data into my django project.

Comment: Share your urls.py that includes your view and also share your view

Comment: name 'port' is not defined

Comment: check view port called but not defined

Comment: I forgot to tell that I'm using express js. I can't include ajax, I'm having error it says that $ is not defined. I have js file.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Is there another way to get the data to another python file? for example I'm using plotly dash and I want to use the POST data. I tried using the request but I think it's not recognizing the request. Do you have another way to access the post request? Can you help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73629005/pass-data-from-views-py-into-the-plotly-dash-callback-function